# Can't run react application with Intellij

Tags: reactjs, linux, intellij-idea, npm

I use linux and I just try to start a react application then I generated from Intellij.

```
Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: linux-66w6
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
Learn more here: https://xxx.x/CRA-advanced-config


Process finished with exit code 2



Compiled successfully!

You can now view premier-projet in the browser.

  http://linux-66w6:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

I'm not able to access

```
http://linux-66w6:3000
```

tried with localhost, 127.0.0.1... same result

In console,  hostnames return

```
linux-66w6
```

Comment: try setting `HOST` to `localhost`, see https://medium.com/@choy/fixing-create-react-app-when-npm-fails-to-start-because-your-host-environment-variable-is-being-4c8a9fa0b461